# What is the best way Mavenizing Ivy managed dependencies for an existing project

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, maven, maven-plugin, ivy

HI need some help or advice on converting or migrating an existing Ivy managed dependencies project to a Maven.

is there any good document or plugin? I am using eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Ivy is an ANT plug-in meaning only responsible for dependency management. An ivy task called called [makepom](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/use/makepom.html) can be used to generate a maven POM from your existing ivy.xml.

Your real challenge is converting your project build over to the "Maven way" of doing things, which means you need to investigate migrating from ANT to Maven.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank indeed that helped me a lot to start with :)

Comment: @MarkO'Connor He probably fell off the face of the earth after getting an answer. Thank you for your answer, still helped me out 8 years later :-)